# Как перехватить тело ответа в расширении Chrome?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Сейчас использую `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(....)...` Заголовки считать могу, а тело ответа никак.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению никак.
`chrome.webRequest` не дает возможности "увидеть" тело запроса.

Если запрос идемпотентный - можно повторно обратиться по перехваченному URL для получения тела (с помощью XHR/Fetch)